# Reference architecture for RichFaces 4 webapp

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm currently investigating whether I should use GWT 2.4 or RichFaces 4 for a new webapp I'm going to build. I'm aware of many documents describing the architecture of a GWT application, but I haven't really found any extensive descriptions for RichFaces applications.

I found [an old article about JSF with Spring and Hibernate from 2004](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0719-jsf.html), but I'm looking for something more current.

I'm especially interested in how to structure a webapp using RichFaces as UI layer and how to best wire the managed beans to the underlying business logic. Package and class diagrams would come in handy, but also a documented sample app would do the trick.

I would prefer to not have Spring and Hibernate in the example architecture so that I can better compare it to pure GWT webapps.

Do you have any pointers for me? Is there something like a reference architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found an answer by reshaping my question. Instead of looking for specific JSF-related descriptions, I took a more general view on how to structure a JEE6 architecture.

Most useful for me is the [official Oracle JEE6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html) and also the in-depth look at the [JBoss AS 7 Kitchensink example](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/The+kitchensink+example+in+depth).

Answer (score 0):

JBoss has a good tutorial about generating an archetype with Maven for a Richfaces 4 application, on their [Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html). There is said, that the provided Maven archetype generates a structure like this:

```
new_project
├── pom.xml
├── readme.txt
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── org
        │       └── docs
        │           └── richfaces
        │               └── RichBean.java
        └── webapp
            ├── index.xhtml
            ├── templates
            │   └── template.xhtml
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── faces-config.xml
                └── web.xml
```

*(this is a copy about the structure explained in the given source. More information: read the whole guide.)*

Is this quite much what you asked for?

Comment: No, this is just the project layout. I'm looking for the overall class structure and package layout to be used, e.g. to separate client and server code correctly.